# while using Javscript syntax and Testing API using Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

Hi all experts i'm trying to connect to postamn using the below javaScript code,

However the normal connection seems to be fine while i run nodeman, there are no error also while i send the GET request to postman that does work fine, I do not know what I'm doing wrong with POST API request, i tried using ES6 earlier syntax ad well as I'm using ES6 now, but seems like not working.

Please find the code form my app.js file below

```
    const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose');
const user = require('./database/models/user');


/*
install CORS: Cross Origin Request Security
This is basically used to run two ports on same server, 
i.e Front-End: running on localhost:4200 which is using angular framework
BackEnd: localhost: running on 3000- backend api using nodejs, express
*/
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use ((req, res, next) =>{
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH< DELETE" );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
  
});

// app.use(express.json());
// app.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  //     person.find({})
  //     .then(user => res.send(user))
  //     .catch ((error) => console.log(error));
  // })
  app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
      res.send("hello world");
  });


  app.post('/register', (req, res) => {

    // (new User ({
    //   'firstname': req.body.firstname,
    //   'lastname': req.body.lastname,
    //   'email': req.body.email,
    //   'password': req.body.password
    // }))

    // .save()
    // .then((user) => res.send(user))
    //  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    const firstname = req.body.firstname;
    const lastname = req.body.lastname;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    
    
    const user = new User();
    user.firstname = firstname;
    user.lastname = lastname;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = password;
    
    user.save((err, result ) => {
      if(err){
        console.log("There is error adding user to database");
        res.sendStaus(500);
      }
      res.sendStatus(200);
    })
    
  });
  
  
  app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server is Connected to port 3000"));
```

Also please the error which i'm getting her, also i'm new to this developer filed, can anyone correct me?

```
ReferenceError: User is not defined
at C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\app.js:54:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\app.js:21:3
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\tapesh.patel\Desktop\Website\Kare-app\BackEnd\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

I thought there might be parsing issue with Jason so i used Bodyparser while i was using express.json for parsing the code into json. I guess this two are doing the same job.

Still idont know whats missing with JavaScript. I would really appreciate if experts can correct me and help me to learn.

Thanks
Tapesh

Comment: `user` != `User`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have imported your schema with the name `user` while you're trying to use it with the name `User`

Comment: Thank you so much @Abhishekranjan this was really very handy but kept me looking all round for the solution, this helped alot, so kind of you.

Comment: @TapeshPatel Accept this as a answer so that others can find what you were facing easily

Comment: it says that i can only accept after certain time sir. but sure will do it ASAP you being really very helpful :)